# Problem integrating QFontComboBox in Qmenu

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmenu, qfont

I'm trying to integrate QFontComboBox within Qmenu.
I try to make two things happen when selecting a particular font from the menu:

1. The Qmenu will close.
2. print the selected font.

---

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont, QCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QFontComboBox, QWidgetAction, QMenu, QPushButton
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Pyside2 FontCombo Box")
        self.setGeometry(300,200,300,250)
        self.setFontBox()
        self.setIcon()
        self.show()
    def setIcon(self):
        appIcon = QIcon("icon.png")
        self.setWindowIcon(appIcon)
    def setFontBox(self):
        self.font_button = QPushButton(self)
        self.font_button.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.font_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setFontmenu())
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.font_button)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
    def setFontmenu(self):
        font_menu = QMenu()
        font_submenu = QFontComboBox()
        font_submenu.setCurrentFont(QFont("Arial"))
        objectTest = QObject()
        widget = QWidgetAction(objectTest)
        widget.setDefaultWidget(font_submenu)
        font_menu.addAction(widget)
        font_menu.exec_(QCursor.pos())
        menu = font_menu
        menu.addSeparator()
        font_submenu.showPopup()
        font_submenu.setFocus()
        font_submenu.currentFontChanged.connect(self._changed)
    def _changed(self):
        font = self.currentFont().family()
        print(font)
        return
myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
myapp.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense. Most importantly, you're trying to add a separator to the menu, show the popup and connect a signal ***after*** the menu has been shown and (eventually) triggered. Just add a `font` argument to `_changed`, remove the first line (which would be invalid anyway), and also replace all lines after `font_menu.exec_` with `self._changed(font_submenu.currentFont())`.

Comment: This could have been a solution but I need it done before the Qmenu closes

Comment: You don't understand: *everything* after `menu.exec()` will *always* be called **after** the menu closes, also in your code. So, if you want to do something different, please be more clear.